# How do I count the number of lines of code not containing something in a project?

Tags: bash

I have a DNA sequence variance count file, and the file contains a header and the information I need, like this:

```
## XXXXXXXXXX
## XXXXXXXXXX    
1 XXXXXXXXX    
1 XXXXXXXXX    
1 XXXXXXXXXX
```

I only know that I can count the number of lines using `wc -l`

Could someone please help me how I can produce the code to count how many lines are in the file, excluding the lines starting with `##`?

Comment: With `grep` AND `wc`: `grep --invert-match "^##" file | wc -l`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to get the count of lines that don't match the pattern:

```
grep -vc "^##" file
```